# UI Router angularjs Transitions onBefore returning promise uncompiled template flickering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-ui-router, transition

Looking for global fix to prevent uncompiled template flickering

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-ui-router-transition-flicker-8bokfp?file=app.js

In this example above by navigating through A and B components you can see red text flickering while transition happens.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: once the transition is done, are you going to replace the component html with the response ?

Comment: check this if this works for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-ui-router-transition-flicker-malcr9?file=app.js

Comment: @Deep thank you for response, but i cant add any additional code to components. Imagine if i have 1000 components. and no i am not, what you see pretty much is the problem, I use promise on transition and it makes template content flicker

Comment: @TomasLidžius I had this issue as well. It looks like returning Promise in `onBefore` causing this issue. Without further investigation changing my hook from `onBefore` to `onStart` eliminated the flickering issue. In your example as well. Hopefully this will help someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using *UI-Router* you can try with **resolve** to handle asyincronous request before complete the transition.

I replaced your **$transitions.onBefore** hook with this *resolve* state property:

```
$stateProvider
    .state({
        name: 'a',
        url: '/a',
        component: 'componentA',
        resolve: { delay: (delayer) => delayer.apply() }
    });
```

where the **delayer** is a service that apply a delay like your example.

```
angular.module('app')
  .service('delayer', ($http) => {
    return {
        apply: () => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            $http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?delay=0.5')
              .then(() => {
                resolve();
              });
          });
        }
    }
  });
```

No flickering for me we this changes.